# after ESM on makerDao what to access my vault

Tags: azure-qna-maker

I had ESM on MakerDao on April 2023 and I need to know how to access my vault information.

I received mip65 dashboard and a vault loan but I don't know the usage.
my admin account generated me a command and I put that command on my mac terminal also an ssh key generated I don not know where to use ssh key to access? how to getting my ESM whole information or roadmap as per requested from MakerDAO but till now didn't received any update.
how to access my vault? where can I find my vault info?
Regards: hosseinsamet

Comment: Please read tags before using them. I don't think [tag:dao], [tag:mips], [tag:mips32] or [tag:mipmaps] apply here. Is this question related to programming?